# Office Conditional Else Statement

Tags: css, outlook, ms-office

With the following Microsoft Office conditional statement, I can target Outlook version greater than or equal to 2016:

```
<!--[if gte mso 16]><!-->
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr td { line-height: normal !important; }
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

How would I target everything else? Something like an else statement or a "not" statement using an exclamation point:

```
<!--[if !gte mso 16]><!-->
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr td { line-height: normal !important; }
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat Microsoft Office as the only application that understand those comments and provide syntax that will be just ignored by everything else

```
<![if lt mso 16]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table tr td { line-height: normal !important; }
    </style>
<![endif]>
```

Follow this link for more examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-8